# Show/Hide button doesn't work on Mac

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the show/hide button works fine in all the browsers on Windows, but doesn't work as expected in Safari and Google Chrome on Mac. It either doesn't show/hide the list at all, or shows only partial items...
I use [(Son of) Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/)

for the multi-level dropdown.
Here is the URL:
http://eximi.dreamhosters.com/Hawaii/pkdiet/pkd.php

JavaScript for the show/hide button:

```
function toggleDiv()  
      {  
        if (document.getElementById("submenu").style.display == "block")  
        {  
          document.getElementById("submenu").style.display = "none";  
        }  
        else  
        {  
          document.getElementById("submenu").style.display = "block";  
        }  
      }
```

CSS for 'suckerfish' part:

```
#nav, #nav ul {
    float: left;
    width: 14em;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: Tunga, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    w\idth: 6em;
    color: #996637;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.25em 2em;
}

#nav a.daddy {
    background: url(rightarrow2.gif) center right no-repeat;
}

#nav li {
    /*float: left;*/
    padding: 0;
    width: 10em;
}

#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    width: 14.4em;

    font-weight: normal;
    border-width: 0.25em;
    margin-left : 10.05em;
    margin-top : -1.35em;
}

#nav li li {
    padding-right: 1em;
    width: 13em
}

#nav li ul a {
    width: 13em;
    w\idth: 9em;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    margin: -1.75em 0 0 14em;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

You can see the HTML in the source code on the URL above.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

in you suckerfish.js I am getting this errors on google chrome:

```
uncought SyntaxError: unexpectect token <
```

While in Firefox it works but is throwing me this error:

```
XML can't be the whole program 
//--><!]]></script>
```

It seems that your XML structure comments are messing you up, the only difference is that chrome stops at the begging in line one and firefox at the end

Comment: Hah, +1 for beating me to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

I guess there is no element with ID "submenu" on your page of some reason.

As well in Chrome the input element containing the "onClick" function is slightly above the button.

Comment: Yes, there is <div> with "submenu" ID on my page. It comes with the included file.

Could this JavaScript be problematic? -

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

sfHover = function() {
 var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
 for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
  sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
   this.className+=" sfhover";
  }
  sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
   this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
  }
 }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);

//--><!]]></script>

Comment: Yeah, the suckerfish.js contains html script-tags "<script ...>" which gives the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". The .js file should only contain javascript, or at least commented script tags.

Comment: I removed those tags and it still didn't fix the problem.
I myself cannot test it on Mac, but here is what I've got from my client:
"safari
chrome

    do not work on Mac Os 10.7 LION nor does it work on  Mac Os 10.6 SNOW LEOPARD.






FIREFOX
OPERA
IPAD
IPHONE

    Works on Mac Os 10.7 LION  and  Mac Os 10.6 SNOW LEOPARD."

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the script itself, but in the way you formed the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
...
//--><!]]></script>
```

This can just be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

Or if you feel like keeping the CDATA for XML validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
...
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Should these tags <script type="text/javascript">
</script> be included in the file if I make a separate .js file out of the script?
Or I should only use them when I reference that file in my HTML?

Comment: Thank you! :)
One last question:
how do I know what's going on with my code on Mac if I don't have a Mac computer?

Comment: It should work the same for Windows Safari as Mac Safari. If that is not the case, problems like this would be caught by a validator such as http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

suckerfish:js Line 1: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Get that out of there and you're good to go.

Comment: I removed <script type="text/javascript">
and
</script>

I am a total stranger to JavaScript.
Thank you so much!
By the way, what software do you use to debug it?

Comment: View -> Developer -> Javascript Console : Console tools are HUGE help, you're in for a *world of awesome* once you find out more about them.